# How to find installation mode of Hadoop 2.x

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

what is the quickest way of finding the installation mode of the Hadoop 2.x?

I just want to learn the best way to find the mode when I login first time into a Hadoop installed machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In hadoop 2 - go to /etc/hadoop/conf folder and check the Fs.defaultFS in core-site.xml and Yarn.resourcemanager.hostname property in yarn-site.xml. The values for those properties decide which mode you are running in.

**Fs.defaultFS**

```
Standalone mode   - file:///
pseudo distributed- hdfs://localhost:8020/
Fully distributed - hdfs://namenodehostname:8020/
```

**Yarn.resourcemanager.hostname**

```
Standalone mode    - file:///
pseudo distributed - hdfs://localhost:8021/
Fully ditributed   - hdfs://resourcemanagerhostname:8021/
```

Alternatively you can use jps command to check the mode. if you see namenode/secondary namenode /jobtracker daemons running separately then it is distributed.

similarly in MR1 go to /etc/hadoop/conf folder and check the fs.default.name in core-site.xml and mapred.job.tracker property in mapred-site.xml.

Comment: is this for 2.x ? I just checked on Cloudera 2.5.0-cdh5.3.3  and couldn't find the nodes you stated. core-site.xml has fs.defaultFS node with the value of hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020 Also- mapred-site.xml has no mapred.job.tracker node.

Comment: I gave these properties for MR1. I have modified my post to reflect for MR2. In CDH5 you can work on both MR1 and MR2.