# hadoop streaming, using -libjars to include jar files

Tags: java, python, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I'm learning hadoop, and wrote map/reduce steps to process some avro files I have.  I think the problem I am having may be due to my hadoop install though.  I am trying to test in standalone mode on my laptop, not on a distributed cluster.

Here is my bash call to run the job:

```
#!/bin/bash

reducer=/home/hduser/python-hadoop/test/reducer.py  
mapper=/home/hduser/python-hadoop/test/mapper.py
avrohdjar=/home/hduser/python-hadoop/test/avro-mapred-1.7.4-hadoop1.jar
avrojar=/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar


hadoop jar ~/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming* \
  -D mapreduce.job.name="hd1" \
  -libjars ${avrojar},${avrohdjar} \ 
  -files   ${avrojar},${avrohdjar},${mapper},${reducer} \
  -input   ~/tmp/data/* \
  -output  ~/tmp/data-output \
  -mapper  ${mapper} \
  -reducer ${reducer} \
  -inputformat org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroAsTextInputFormat
```

And here's the output:

```
15/04/23 11:02:54 INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is
deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
15/04/23 11:02:54 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
15/04/23 11:02:54 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
15/04/23 11:02:54 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area file:/home/hduser/tmp/mapred/staging/hduser1337717111/.staging/job_local1337717111_0001
15/04/23 11:02:54 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Error launching job , bad input path : File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:54310/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar
Streaming Command Failed!
```

I've tried a lot of different fixes, but have no idea what to try next.  For some reason hadoop can't find the jar files specified by -libjars.  Also, I have successfully run the wordcount example posted [here](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/), so my hadoop install or configuration works well enough for that.  Thanks!

**EDIT**
Here are the changes of the contents of my hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
  <description>Default block replication.
   The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
  The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
  </description>
</property>
```

And here is core-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/home/hduser/tmp</value>
  <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
  <description>The name of the default file system.  A URI whose
  scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation.  The
  uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming
  the FileSystem implementation class.  The uri's authority is used to
  determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.</description>
</property>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your cluster is running in distributed mode. It is trying to look for the input at the following path and that path doesnt exist.

```
hdfs://localhost:54310/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar
```

Comment: Oh, huh.  I followed this tutorial (top answer) on the setup: http://askubuntu.com/questions/144433/how-to-install-hadoop   How do I change it to non-distributed mode?  Also, what is the way to check which mode I am running in?

Comment: can you check your core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml and post it here. it will be point to the file system that points to hdfs://. If you want to run in standalone, it should be file:/// ...        check this once. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721623/how-to-find-installation-mode-of-hadoop-2-x/29721955#29721955

Comment: Changing hdfs://.... to file:/// fixed it.  Now I have new errors to fix.  Thank you!